# Wordpress get id from json data with json_decode()

Tags: plugins

I add on my wordpress a function to save a json file , when a post is saved on admin. Basically i get the title ( that will be a json string ) and convert it to JSON.
From that JSON i need to extract the id , to use like a name of the file created. But when i try to get the id , i have an empty value.

```
    add_action('save_post', function($ID, $post) {
         // The $ID of post is different from ID that i have in post_title string
         $encoded_post = wp_json_encode( $post->post_title );
         $post_decode  = json_decode( $encoded_post, true );

         // Get the id from decoded data, converted from string to json
         $data = json_decode( $post->post_title );
         // ID of json given
         $ID = $data->id;


        // Dir to save the file
         $dir = plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ );

         // Post name and ext
         $file_path =  $ID .'.json';
        //"$post_name'.json'";

        file_put_contents($dir.$file_path, $post_decode);
    }, 10, 2);
```

Comment: I don't believe this is a WordPress problem or that WordPress expertise is relevant here. This is a general PHP problem that any PHP dev could help with, JSON decoding. Is this the full code? Your decode should not have an ID field because you never added one, `$post_decode = json_decode( json_encode( $post->post_title ) )` is the same as what you put, so where did the ID date and title keys come from? And why are you trying to encode and decode repeatedly? Is the post title itself the JSON string? This doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_encode` takes an array/object and turns it into a JSON string.

`json_decode` takes a JSON string and turns it into a PHP array/object/etc

With this in mind, we can see some critical mistakes are made in the code, caused by muddling up the two.

1. You're taking a string of JSON and JSON encoding it, aka double JSON encoding it, which doesn't make sense. Think of it like doing this: `json_encode( json_encode( ['ID' => 2] ) )`
2. You're then immediatley decoding it, so `$post_decode` and `$post->title` are the same, it's like turning on the light switch then turning it off everytime you go past, it's a non-operation, nothing is achieved
3. Then, for some reason `json_encode` is called, but it's called on a nonexistant value. Remember, `$post_decode` is not an array/object, it's a JSON string that hasn't been decoded, what you're doing is the same as `$foo = 'bar'; echo $foo->ID;`. Expect this to generate huge amounts of PHP notices and warnings in your PHP error log.

This is all very confusing and unnecessary.

Instead take your post title and decode it from JSON into an object:

```php
$data = json_decode( $post->post_title );
```

Then use it:

```php
$ID = $data->id;
```

Comment: Thank you Tom, now it work. I've update the code snipped aswell. Thanks for help

Comment: by doing that you make your question very confusing for future readers as the problem has been removed from the code. You should change it back

Answer (score -1):

```php
add_action('save_post', function($ID, $post) {
    // The $ID of post is different from ID that i have in post_title string

   // In field post_title i have the json string, that i will convert to json
    $parse_post = json_encode($post->post_title); 

    // Here is the error: Your are decoding $parse_post while parsed post has encoded $post->post_title.
    $encoded_post = wp_json_encode( $post );
    $post_decode  = json_decode( $encoded_post );
    // Post Decode return this 

    // {"id":"9566","date":"2021-07-28T17:12:31","title":"test post" }

    // Here is the issue, i need to get the id from json in $post_decode
    $post_name = isset( $post_decode->ID ) ? $post_decode->ID : $post_decode->id;

    // Dir to save the file
    $dir = plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ );

    // Here i need to add the id inside $parse_post json string
    $file_path =  "$post_name'.json'";
    
    // Not show any result
     print_r($file_path);

    file_put_contents($dir.$file_path, $post_decode);
}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Sorry that not work in that case, it take the ID from post. I need to get the id , inside the string in title field .
    $parse_post = json_encode($post->post_title); 
    
    // ---- > {"id":"9566","date":"2021-07-28T17:12:31","title":"test post" }

I need to get this, the post id is different.

Comment: I've downvoted as this answer is just a code snippet with no explanation of what the solution is, why it works, or what was changed

Comment: In fairness the explanation is in comments in the code.